# How can I ignore folder name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a local wordpress website on IP "192.168.0.115".
There is a page in it called "Invoice" ("192.168.0.115/invoice").
I have about 800 PDF (invoice) files.
I would like their URL to be "192.168.0.115/invoice/invoice001.pdf", "...002.pdf" and so on.

What I did:
I made a folder called "invoice" in the htdocs folder next to "wp-admin", "wp-content" and "wp-includes" where I put all 800 PDF files.
It worked out - when I entered the URL "192.168.0.115/invoice/invoice001.pdf" it opened the desired PDF file.
But when I entered the url "192.168.0.115/invoice" I had no longer access to the page "Invoice".
Instead I got all of the files listed as in a folder through the browser.
I couldn't access the page, because of the same folder name and same page name -> "invoice".

My question:
Is there any way I can tell wordpress to ignore the folder called "invoice" and load the page with URL "192.168.0.115/invoice" AND in the same time open files with URL "192.168.0.115/invoice/invoice001.pdf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using apache you can add a rewrite rule to your .htaccess file.

You can't have a WordPress page and a folder named that same thing.  So the first thing you need to do is change your folder name from `invoice` to `my-invoices`.  Then you add this rule to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^invoice/(.*).pdf$ my-invoices/$1.pdf
```

Don't forget to rename your folder, but leave your WordPress page slug.

Then you'll be able to go to each of these URLs:

```
http://192.168.0.115/invoice/
http://192.168.0.115/invoice/invoice001.pdf
```

Be sure to place your new rewrite rule above the ones for WordPress.

Comment: I have just tried it and it's working! Thank you very much!